# Postgresql: getting exception when trying to connect to the DB

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgresql version 12.0.
From my Java program I do:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(new SimpleTimeZone(offset, zoneId, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0));
```

When zoneId is "ART" or "EAT"
and my Java program tries to connect to the DB I get this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "ART"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2618) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:135) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:250) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
```

(Same exception with "TimeZone": "EAT".)

Setting other zoneIds works fine.

**Why this exception happens with "ART" and "EAT" zone ids?**

**Is there a list or a pattern of valid zone ids so I avoid setting an invalid zone id?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this blog post: https://blog.afnf.net/blog/68

It looks like you may have stumbled across a timezone which is not supported by the Postgres server.  The page shows how you can look at the contents of /usr/local/pgsql/share/timezone/ to provide you a list of supported timezones.

It also appears that you can list this via a postgres system table/view: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/view-pg-timezone-names.html

Perhaps connect using UTC and select from this view to see what time zones are supported.

Answer (score 0):

'ART' seems to be an abbreviation for Argentina time.  According to [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) "You cannot set the configuration parameters TimeZone or log_timezone to a time zone abbreviation" (although a few abbreviations are also treated as being full names as well, 'ART' is not one of them).  You can instead use the full name:

```
set timezone TO 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires';
```